# How to read a pipe delimited txt file into an NSDictionay

Tags: objective-c

my txt file looks like this

```
Blue|Big
Red|medium
Yellow|small
```

What would be the best way to create a NSDictionary from this txt file?

I have considered componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"

The output should be something like

```
@{@"Blue": @"Big", @"Red": @"medium", @"Yellow": @"small"}
```

EDIT: correctly formatted the text file

Comment: Please specify how the final dictionary should appear. Should it be something like `@{@"Blue": @"Big", @"Red": @"medium", @"Yellow": @"small"}`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly how it should be

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: And is it always the case that the key-value pairs are separated from each other with spaces? Can either keys or values have spaces in them? If so, how would you determine how things should be split up?

Comment: The delimiter is a pipe | symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:someURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[text enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop){
    NSArray* keyAndValue = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    NSString* key = keyAndValue.firstObject;
    NSString* value = keyAndValue.lastObject;
    dict[key] = value;
}];
```

Comment: Sorry there was an error in my question. the lines in the text file have a carriage return at the end

Comment: not sure I can use stringWithContentsOfURL as my file is loaded from the filesystem not a url

Comment: It's common to have URLs for files on the file system. In fact, that's what Apple recommends. File paths in strings are somewhat discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
//Extracting File Path
NSString* yourFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
               pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"txt"];

//Reading File
NSString* fileContents = 
      [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:yourFile 
       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//Splitted using pipeline which will return array
NSArray* allLinedStrings =
[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *str in allLinedStrings)
{
    NSArray *ar=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    [dict setObject:ar[1]  forKey:ar[0]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

Comment: This will not yield a dictionary as the asker wants. See my comment on the question for an example of how the dictionary should appear.